# How is the value object constructed in case key is not present while using [] operator for an unordered_map?

Tags: c++, operators, unordered-map

In an unordered_map, when we use the [] operator to get the value for a key, then if the key is not present, it performs an insertion. I want to understand how it is implemented.

```
std::unordered_map<int, int> x;
x[1] = 10;
```

In the above statement, how is the rvalue 10 accessed and used to perform an insertion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very straightforward.

Operator `[]` for `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` looks for an element with a given key. If the element is present, it returns the reference to the `second` member of it's pair. If it is not present, it creates a new pair, with a key (`first`) equal to given key and [value-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) `second`, inserts this element and returns reference to the `second`.

Then `operator=` works normally.

Comment: what if the default constructor is deleted for the value type ?

Comment: @dummy _"what if the default constructor is deleted for the value type ?"_ The compiler would complain.

Comment: @dummy than attempt to use `operator[]` will trigger compilation error. The constant source of frustration is that it will happen even if in your use-case the value will always be there.

Comment: @dummy Then you can't use `operator[]`.

Comment: Nit: the missing value is *value-initialized*, not *default-constructed*. For example, if the type is `int`, you are guaranteed to get 0.

Comment: My confusion was only related to the default construction in case there is no default constructor. Infact, I didn't thought to try it out which would have given the compilation error. I didn't expected it to be so trivial. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @dummy good question is 50% of the answer. If you'd asked the real question from the very beginning, you'd probably realize that it is easier to check by compiling the code.